# How to solve psycopg2 and postgresql, psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable relation does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am developing very simple API in python (Flask), that will query Postgres database and return json result. The SQL query is: `SELECT * FROM estates WHERE id_estate = %s`

Error: `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "estates" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM estates WHERE id_estate = '1'`

Querying the database looks like this.

```
conn = DatabaseManager.get_connection()
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM estates WHERE id_estate = %s""", (estate_id,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

The database and server is running in docker. I am using generic postgres image. It is very strange, that even though I use docker, this issue does not occur on my machine (MacOS), but does occur on VPS (debian). At this moment I am lost and I would appreciate any advice.

The data were exported from the Postgres running on my machine and imported to the remote one. Export -> SQL and then executed through DataGrip. I've altered sequences then to have the correct ids.

I've tried changing python webservers, changing the table from estates to public.estates, "estates", public."estates" but it didn't work.

Comment: My guess is you try to use different postgres instance than you think. Look into the connection url you provide while creating a connection and use postgress client (like `psql`) to connect there

Comment: Or the table name is mixed/upper case and you will need to do `... FROM "ESTATES" ...` or whatever the case is for the name. Use `psql` to verify.

Comment: @kosciej16 thank you, while I was connecting to the server with DataGrip, for some reason I connected to postgres DB not the one I had in .env. It's funny, because I could swear I specified it. Simple mistake and it took to long to solve.